# ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have this anonymous PL/SQL block which calculates and prints a value return from a table.

```
DECLARE
    U_ID NUMBER :=39;
    RETAIL BINARY_FLOAT:=1;
    FLAG NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(RETAIL_AMOUNT,1),UNIT_ID INTO RETAIL, FLAG FROM UNITS WHERE UNIT_ID=U_ID;
    LOOP
    SELECT NVL(MAX(UNIT_ID),U_ID) INTO FLAG FROM  UNITS WHERE FATHER_ID=FLAG;
    IF FLAG=U_ID THEN EXIT; END IF;
    SELECT RETAIL* RETAIL_AMOUNT INTO RETAIL FROM UNITS WHERE UNIT_ID=FLAG;
    EXIT WHEN FLAG=U_ID;
    END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( RETAIL);
END;
```

This block work correctly, but I wanted to do the same thing using a PL/SQL Function

I wrote the function as follow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_UNIT_RETAIL(U_ID NUMBER)
     RETURN NUMBER
IS
    RETAIL BINARY_FLOAT:=1;
    FLAG NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(RETAIL_AMOUNT,1),UNIT_ID 
    INTO RETAIL, FLAG 
    FROM UNITS 
    WHERE UNIT_ID=U_ID;

    LOOP
        SELECT NVL(MAX(UNIT_ID),U_ID) 
        INTO FLAG 
        FROM  UNITS 
        WHERE FATHER_ID=FLAG;
        IF FLAG=U_ID THEN 
            EXIT; 
        END IF;
        SELECT RETAIL* RETAIL_AMOUNT 
        INTO RETAIL 
        FROM UNITS 
        WHERE UNIT_ID=FLAG;
        EXIT WHEN FLAG=U_ID;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN NUMBER;
END;
/
```

When I try to execute the above code to save the function to the database, the environment (SQL*PLUS) hangs for a long time and at the end returns this error:

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object

What is the problem ??? Please !

Comment: I would assume that you have an infinite loop problem because the exit condition is never true.  But you are in the best position to disect the logic and explain what is happening here.

Comment: there is no infinite loop, look at the previous code, the code execute correctly, and do the same thing by the same way.

Comment: `the environment (SQL*PLUS) hangup` ... then what do you mean by this?

Comment: I'm guessing he meant it hangs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like **ddl_lock** problem

Take a look at
`dba_ddl_locks` to see who is "blocking" a create or replace.

Also try to create under ***different name*** - and see what happens.

Comment: finally SQL*PLUS returned: 
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object.

what does that mean? Please!

Comment: @SaddamMeshaal it means that Oracle thinks that the resource you are trying to replace is in use.. it waits for lock to be released (that is why it 'hangs') and finally it times out. So simple,temporary solution - change function name and run again. More sophisticated, long-term solution would be determining what/who is using the resource, stop the usage (either by killing session or more subtly)  and then run `create or replace`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because the Object `GET_UNIT_RETAIL` was busy by other environment
Here is the answer:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2321256