# Updating Oracle PL SQL Package Causes ORA 04021 Error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am trying to update a package previously creating by running the following code in SQL Developer (Oracle 11g)

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE package_name AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS
  PROCEDURE timesecond(proc_name IN VARCHAR2, 
  starttime IN TIMESTAMP, endtime in TIMESTAMP);
  PROCEDURE drop_tables;
  PROCEDURE create_tables;
  ...

END package_name;
```

I am getting the following error:

> ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object 
>   04021. 00000 -  "timeout occurred while waiting to lock object %s%s%s%s%s"
>   *Cause:    While waiting to lock a library object, a timeout is occurred.
>   *Action:   Retry the operation later.

I used to be able to update my package when I ran it on SQL developer, but I also ran it on SQLPLUS a few days ago (although that session ended when I disconnected from the server I'm using to do all of this work).

I tried to run this process but it takes too long. Any idea what could be the issue?

```
SELECT SID, OWNER, OBJECT, TYPE
FROM V$ACCESS
WHERE OBJECT LIKE '%OBJECT%';
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051788/ora-04021-timeout-occurred-while-waiting-to-lock-object)